# Adding lists in a python elif statements

Tags: python-2.7

I have two data files (datafile1 and datafile2) and I want to add some information from datafile2 to datafile1, but only if it meets certain requirements, and then write all of the information to new file.

Here is an example of datafile1 (I changed the tabs so it's easier to see):

```
#OTU    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 Seq
OTU49   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   catat
OTU171  5   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   gattt
OTU803  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   aactt
OTU2519 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   aattt
```

Here is an example of datafile2:

```
#GInumber   OTU     Accssn      Ident   Len M   Gap Qs  Qe  Ss  Se  evalue      bit phylum      class       order           family          genus       species
1366104624  OTU49   MG926900    82.911  158 23  4   2   157 18  173 2.17e-29    139 Arthropoda  Insecta     Hymenoptera     Braconidae      Leiophron   NA
342734543   OTU171  JN305047    95.513  156 7   0   2   157 23  178 9.63e-63    250 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     Limacodidae     Euphobetron Euphobetron cupreitincta
290756623   OTU803  GU580785    96.753  154 5   0   4   157 10  163 5.75e-65    257 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     Geometridae     Apocheima   Apocheima pilosaria
296792336   OTU2519 GU688553    98.039  153 3   0   1   153 18  170 9.56e-68    267 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     Geometridae     Operophtera     Operophtera brumata
```

What I would like to do is for every line of datafile1, find the line in datafile2 with the same "OTU", and from datafile 2 always add GInumber, Accssn, Ident, Len, M, Gap, Qs, Qe, Ss, Se, evalue, bit, phylum, and class. If Ident falls between certain numbers, then I would like to also add order, family, genus, and species, according to these criteria:

```
Case #1: Ident > 98.0, add order, family, genus, and species
Case #2: Ident between 96.5 and 98.0, add order, family, "NA", "NA"
Case #3: Ident between 95.0 and 96.5, add order, "NA", "NA", "NA"
Case #4: Ident < 95.0 add "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"
```

The desired output would be this:

```
#OTU    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 Seq     GInumber    Accssn      Ident   Len M   Gap Qs  Qe  Ss  Se  evalue      bit phylum      class       order           family          genus       species
OTU49   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   catat   1366104624  MG926900    82.911  158 23  4   2   157 18  173 2.17e-29    139 Arthropoda  Insecta     NA  NA  NA  NA
OTU171  5   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   gattt   342734543   JN305047    95.513  156 7   0   2   157 23  178 9.63e-63    250 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     NA  NA  NA
OTU803  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   aactt   290756623   GU580785    96.753  154 5   0   4   157 10  163 5.75e-65    257 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     Geometridae     NA  NA
OTU2519 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   aattt   296792336   GU688553    98.039  153 3   0   1   153 18  170 9.56e-68    267 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     Geometridae     Operophtera     Operophtera brumata
```

I wrote this script:

```
import csv

#Files
besthit_taxonomy_unique_file = "datafile2.txt"
OTUtablefile = "datafile1.txt"
outputfile = "outputfile.txt"

#Settings
OrderLevel = float(95.0)
FamilyLevel = float(96.5)
SpeciesLevel = float(98.0)


#Importing the OTU table, which is tab delimited
OTUtable = list(csv.reader(open(OTUtablefile, 'rU'), delimiter='\t'))
headerOTUs = OTUtable.pop(0)

#Importing the best hit taxonomy table, which is tab delimited
taxonomytable = list(csv.reader(open(besthit_taxonomy_unique_file, 'rU'), delimiter='\t')) 
headertax = taxonomytable.pop(0)
headertax.pop(1)

#Getting the header info
totalheader  = headerOTUs + headertax


#Merging and assigning the taxonomy at the appropriate level
outputtable = []
NAs = 4 * ["NA"]  #This is a list of NAs so that I can add the appropriate number, depending on the Identity
for item in OTUtable:
    OTU = item #Just to prevent issues with the list of lists
    OTUIDtable = OTU[0]
    print OTUIDtable
    for thing in taxonomytable:
        row = thing #Just to prevent issues with the list of lists
        OTUIDtax = row[1]
        if OTUIDtable == OTUIDtax:
            OTU.append(row[0])
            OTU += row[2:15]
            PercentID = float(row[3])
            if PercentID >= SpeciesLevel:   
                OTU += row[15:]
            elif FamilyLevel <= PercentID < SpeciesLevel:
                OTU += row[15:17]
                OTU += NAs[:2]
            elif OrderLevel <= PercentID < FamilyLevel:
                print row[15]
                OTU += row[15]
                OTU += NAs[:3]
            else:
                OTU += NAs  
    outputtable.append(OTU)             

#Writing the output file                    
f1 = open(outputfile, 'w')
for item in totalheader[0:-1]:
    f1.write(str(item) + '\t')
f1.write(str(totalheader[-1]) + '\n')   
for row in outputtable:
    currentrow = row
    for item in currentrow[0:-1]:
        f1.write(str(item) + '\t')
    f1.write(str(currentrow[-1]) + '\n')
```

For the most part the output is correct, except in case #3 (Ident between 95 and 96.5), when the script outputs the entry for order with every letter having a tab between it.

Here is an example of the output:

```
#OTU    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10 S11 S12 S13 S14 S15 S16 S17 S18 Seq     GInumber    Accssn      Ident   Len M   Gap Qs  Qe  Ss  Se  evalue      bit phylum      class       order           family          genus       species
OTU49   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   catat   1366104624  MG926900    82.911  158 23  4   2   157 18  173 2.17e-29    139 Arthropoda  Insecta     NA  NA  NA  NA
OTU171  5   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   gattt   342734543   JN305047    95.513  156 7   0   2   157 23  178 9.63e-63    250 Arthropoda  Insecta     L   e   p   i   d   o   p   t   e   r   a       NA  NA  NA
OTU803  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   aactt   290756623   GU580785    96.753  154 5   0   4   157 10  163 5.75e-65    257 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     Geometridae     NA  NA
OTU2519 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   aattt   296792336   GU688553    98.039  153 3   0   1   153 18  170 9.56e-68    267 Arthropoda  Insecta     Lepidoptera     Geometridae     Operophtera     Operophtera brumata
```

I just can't figure out what's going wrong. The rest of the time the order seems to contain the correct info, but for this one case it seems as if the information in order is stored as a list of lists. However, the output to the screen is this:

```
OTU171
Lepidoptera
```

This doesn't seem to indicate a list of lists...

I would be happy for any insights. I also appreciate if anyone has ideas for making my code more pythonic.

Andreanna

Comment: Strings in Python are iterable. That's why adding them to a list gives you a list of characters. A quick fix would be to make a list out of the input, i.e. `[row]` or `['Lepidoptera']`.

Comment: Thanks! The script works if I change `OTU += row[15]` to `OTU += [row[15]]`

Comment: I've been thinking about this, and I still don't understand why python was iterating over the characters in this particular case, but not for the other cases. Do you know why?

Comment: That's probably because in this case you were only referencing one item in the list `row[15]`. Otherwise you're always referencing a sub-list.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind for the future!